# IBM Data Catalog - Add to Project doesn't show All my Projects

Tags: ibm-data-catalog

I have almost 10+ Projects created in Watson Data Platform.
I created a Data Catalog and added some data assets csv.

Now i am trying to add the dataset to existing projects.

[image]

But it only shows one project out of my 10 projects.
[image]

Can you please help?

Thanks,
Charles.

Answer (score 1):

I found out following:-
This screen lists/pulls all projects that are restricted, all projects that are bluemix COS types, all projects you have permissions to.

[image]

Restricted means Under Project Settings -> Project Scope should be restricted to who can collaborate should set to Yes. The same option is being asked when you create the project. It restricts only users who are part of your Bluemix Organization to be added as collaborators.
[image]

Also the project should be using Cloud Object Storage as Storage.
[image]

Hope others find this useful.

Thanks,
Charles.